# Django cant pass id with url

Tags: python, django, url

I have read a number of other posts and the django docs and as far as i can tell i am doing this correctly but for some reason it is not working. I want to pass an items id through the url the correct way.

This works

```
<a href="/item_details/{{recent.id}}">
```

But this doesn't

```
<a href="{% url 'my_app:item_details' recent.id %}">
```

or this

```
<a href="{% url 'item_details' recent.id %}">
```

urls

```
url(r'^item_details/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', views.item_details, name='view_item_details'),
```

full code

```
{% for recent, images in recent_and_images %}
        <div class="item-wrapper">
            <div class="item-image-wrapper">
              <a href="{% url 'item_details' recent.id %}">
                <img src="{{images.0}}" width="300" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

error

```
Reverse for 'item_details' with arguments '(99,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Also my project is on Django 1.9. I checked the docs and they seem to implement this the same way however.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse searches for `name` attribute. Not the name of the function. So in your case you named your url `view_item_details` and you are passing `item_details`, which is incorrect. Django passes this value to `reverse` function and fetches the full URL automatically, And when it can't find a matching URL you get the `reverse` error. So replace your line in your template with this and it should work

`<a href="{% url 'view_item_details' recent.id %}">`

Comment: Although probably better to change the name, there isn't a good reason to prefix it with "view_".

Comment: I tried doing it with view_item_details, and also tried removing the 'view' from 'view_item_details' and it still gave me this error Reverse for 'view_item_details' with arguments '(99,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Show the `view_item_details` function. Edit it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2 it will be:

```
{% url 'item_details' item_id=recent.id %}
```

Comment: Could you please add some details to your answer?

Comment: It still isn't valid as per OP's question. As it was a typo.

Comment: Yeah, but it *works in django 2*. I will leave it for future reference.